# how to get an error key in laravel error message array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-5.3

I am trying to retrieve a key from an array using Laravel error dump (`$errors`).

The array looks like this

```
ViewErrorBag {#169 ▼
  #bags: array:1 [▼
    "default" => MessageBag {#170 ▼
      #messages: array:2 [▼
        "name" => array:1 [▼
          0 => "The name field is required."
        ]
        "role_id" => array:1 [▼
          0 => "The role id field is required."
        ]
      ]
      #format: ":message"
    }
  ]
}
```

Using `@foreach` loop to get the error message works fine.

```
@foreach($errors->all() as $error)
     <li>{{$error}}</li>
@endforeach
```

But I want to get that `name` and `role_id`. Is there anyway to achieve that? Thus far i have tried the below and some other methods with no luck.

```
@foreach ($errors->all() as $key => $value)
       Key: {{ $key }}
       Value: {{ $value }}
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's because, the `$errors->all()` returns an array of all the errors for all fields in a single array (numerically indexed).

If you want to loop and want to get each `key => value` pairs then you may try something like this:

```
@foreach($errors->getMessages() as $key => $message)
    {{$key}} = {{$message}}
@endforeach
```

But , you may explicitly get an item from the errors, for example:

```
{{ $errors->first('name') }} // The name field is required.
```

Maybe it's wise to check before you ask for any error for a field using something like this:

```
@if($errors->has('name'))
    {{ $errors->first('name') }}
@endif
```

This'll help you to show each error at the top/bottom of the field that the error belongs to.

Comment: Hello. thanks for the reply. i get this error when i try the first method.
htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given. The second solution works perfect. but i still would like to know how to get that key value because i have to put second solution for each input there is in the form. waiting for a reply.

Comment: nevermind. i used the $key directly on the tags id. i guess trying to print out the $key is the messy part. big thanks :D

Answer (score 7):

Use

```
@foreach($errors->getMessages() as $key => $error )
   Key: {{ $key }}
   Value: {{ $error[0] }}
@endforeach
```

if you var_dump the value of $error, you get an array:

`array(1) { [0]=> string(13) "Successfully!" }`

thus you need the key (0 in our case) of that array to access the message

Answer (score 0):

to loop through errors

```
@foreach($errors->getMessages() as $key => $message)
{{$key}} = {{$message[0]}}
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a list of methods available for your `$error` message bag in Laravel API:
https://laravel.com/api/master/Illuminate/Contracts/Support/MessageBag.html

You can get a list of all error keys with:

```
$error->keys()
```

Or errors list with:

```
$errors->all()
```

Or a specific error by its key with:

```
$error->get('your.key')
```